# Display images in monitor using Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, android

Just started to play with Raspberry Pi we would like build an image slider and video player application with Raspberry Pi.

We have 20 inch full HD screen  (eg : computer monitor)

Here is what we are trying to achieve.

we  have an api service that contains some image url's and video url's it should be displayed in the monitor.

So is it possible to do with Rasberry Pi ie it will handle the API calls and output the images and videos into full HD screen.

Get one suggestion to install an android OS and run a android application to handle api calls,but i think its not a right solution.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Which programming languages do you know ?

Comment: Android and php .medium level knowldge in php web application

Comment: So , Java and PHP ? How good are you with Java ?

Comment: Developed smaller desktop application in java.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ready-made "digital signage" solutions. They have a free and paid version.

- [Screenly](http://www.screeenly.io)
- [info-beamer](http://www.info-beamer.com)
- [Pi Presents](http://pipresents.wordpress.com)

If those do not meet your needs , you could write your own in C++ with Qt5. Qt5 is one of the few frameworks which is properly hardware accelerated , which becomes most important when using the Pi Zero or the first model B. JavaFX and Java3D are lacking in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But how can I control the display monitor over internet .  Info-beamer doesn't say any information about it

Answer (score 0):

You can also check piSignage (pisignage.com) , Digital Signage designed for Raspberry pi.you can try it out for free to see whether it meets your needs.you can display contents via Urls. you can control the time for which a particular image has to be displayed and you can also schedule playlists for different time . Dont know if this meets your needs.